# fscanf not reading file contents ( using pthreads ) in C

Tags: c

I have been having trouble using pthreads and reading from files. Our professor only teaches the theory mostly and I have been struggling to learn. As the title says I am having trouble reading from my file using fscanf. My main function is the following.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 15000

void createandFillFile(char*);
void* determineMin(void*);



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //determins if argc is less than 2
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("format is:./a.out <filename> \n");
        return -1;
    }

    createandFillFile(argv[1]);

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t minThread; //maxThread, avgThread;

    //series of if statements to determine if the pthread functions have been executed correctly
    if(pthread_attr_init(&attr) != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: THREAD INITIATION FAILURE");
        return -1;
    }

    if(pthread_create(&minThread,&attr,determineMin,(void*)argv) != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: THREAD CREATION FAILURE");
        return -1;
    }

    if(pthread_join(minThread,NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: THREAD JOIN FAILURE");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My function that creates the file and then fills it with 15000 numbers within the range of -200 to 200 is the following.

```
{
    //creates the file pointer
    FILE *fileptr;

    //creates the file
    fileptr = fopen(fileName,"w");


    int lower = -200;
    int upper = 200;

    int number;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        number = (rand() % (upper-lower+1))+lower;
        fprintf(fileptr,"%i ",number);

    }

    fclose(fileptr);
}
```

And the last function that is using the pthread minThread is the following.

```
void* determineMin(void* fileName)
{
    //creates the file pointer
    FILE *fileptr;

    //creates the file
    fileptr = fopen(*(char**)fileName,"r");

    int number=0, min=0;

    if(fileptr)
    {

        fscanf(fileptr,"%i ",&number);

        min = number;

        printf("%i",min);
    }

    fclose(fileptr);
}
```

The problem i am running into is this. After type casting and de-referencing the void* fileName and opening the file using it. The file opens successfully, but it wont read any input. I'm not currently iterating through every single number because there is 15000, so I am only trying it once, and it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a rule of using files with pthreads that I am forgetting that is preventing from the fscanf from working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re passing `argv` as the thread argument. So `*(char**)fileName` is actually `argv[0]` which is definitely not what you want. Try `((char**)fileName)[1]`.

P.S. You can use `NULL` in place of `&attr` IIRC (if you don’t actually need the attributes ofc).

Comment: This was it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You passed the `argv` as parameter of `pthread_create()`.
It's similar with `argv[0]` and it means the executable file itself.
To pass the file name, please replace `argv` with `argv[1]`.